# Wordpress plugin for admin (Administrators) and users (Editors, Authors , contributors etc )

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress plugin that gives different permissions to different users (administrators, editors, authors, contributors, subscribers). I have been able to make the plugin work perfectly on the administrator's panel or page / end, but when I log in as an editor I can not see the plugin on the sidebar of their page.

How can I show this for the different users?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_menu');

function admin_menu(){
    add_menu_page('Plugin Title', 'Plugin menu name', 'manage_options', 'pl_plugins','plugin_function');
    add_users_page('Plugin Title', 'Plugin menu name', 'read', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_user_plugin_function');
}

function plugin_function() {
}

function my_user_plugin_function(){
}
```

I want the plugin to be able to fetch a certain page when a certain type of user logs in.

Comment: editor role does not have permission `manage_options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected. I tested on localhost and I was able to view the menu in this line as an administrator.

`add_menu_page('Plugin Title', 'Plugin menu name', 'manage_options', 'pl_plugins','plugin_function');`

and this line as an editor (as a submenue under profile menu):
`add_users_page('Plugin Title', 'Plugin menu name', 'read', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_user_plugin_function');`

The third parameter in both functions is the permission level the user needs to access the menu, you can change it to any of the ones here [Roles](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#roles)

Answer (score 1):

You can do check by current user role.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Your CODE with user capability check
    if ( current_user_can('user_role') ) { 
        // Your CODE
    }
```